# How to bring a window to front using terminal command

Tags: x11

Knowing a window handle obtained like this:

```
xwininfo -root -tree -children|grep -i "some window title"
```

I need to bring it to front. What is a command for this? Or if no such command exists, how to code one quickly?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install wmctrl that works withmost window managers and then:

```
wmctrl -a "any substring from a window title"
```